# data.table binary search fails if j refers to a numeric (extra) key column?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider a `data.table`

```
dt = data.table(id = rep(c('a','b'), each=2), 
                val = rep(c(1,2,3), times=c(1,2,1)))
# > dt
#    id val
# 1:  a   1
# 2:  a   2
# 3:  b   2
# 4:  b   3
```

that we want to subset by `id`. 
If we key by that column alone, no problem.

```
setkey(dt, id)
dt[J('a'), val]
#    id val
# 1:  a   1
# 2:  a   2
dt[J('a'), range(val)]
#    id V1
# 1:  a  1
# 2:  a  2
```

But if `dt` happens to be keyed *also* by the numeric column `val`, then that extra key column no longer seems to work in `j`.

```
setkey(dt, id, val)
dt[J('a'), val]
#    id val
# 1:  a   1
dt[J('a'), range(val)]
#    id V1
# 1:  a  1
# 2:  a  1
## I would have expected same results here as when key(dt) == "id" only
```

Some values seem to be missing now...

unless we resort to vector scan (which can be slow, and returns vectors here)

```
dt[id == 'a', val]
# [1] 1 2
dt[id == 'a', range(val)]
# [1] 1 2
```

*or* unless we explicitly set `by` (which throws a warning).

```
dt[J('a'), range(val), by = id]
#    id V1
# 1:  a  1
# 2:  a  2
# Warning message:
# In `[.data.table`(dt, J("a"), range(val), by = id) :
#   by is not necessary in this query; it equals all the join columns 
#   in the same order. j is already evaluated by group of x that each 
#   row of i matches to (by-without-by, see ?data.table). Setting by 
#   will be slower because a subset of x is taken and then grouped
#   again. Consider removing by, or changing it.
```

What's going on please?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.0    reshape2_1.2.2 stringr_0.6.2 
[5] tools_3.0.1
```

Comment: @Arun, I just had a chance to try this on another machine with older version data.table_1.8.10. Using that version, the numeric key seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update: Added test in [commit 1309](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/9b7194649de7da874dfb7e18a89ab036088df890) to catch regressions on this issue at any later stages. Closes [#734](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/734). From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> Added tests (1351.1 and 1351.2) to catch any future regressions on particular case of binary search based subset reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24729001/559784) on SO. Thanks to Scott for the post. The regression was contained to v1.9.2 AFAICT. Closes [#734](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/704).

Scott, thanks for the report (and the follow-up comment). It seems to have occurred in 1.9.2 alone. I tested it on the [current development version v1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) and things seem to work as intended. Please check the README file for installation instructions.

I've added a issue [#734](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/734) to remind us to add a test to cover this usage so that we don't miss it again during any changes in the future.

Comment: Happy to learn this was isolated and fixed now. Thanks for your work on this very useful package.